# ColorBox - popup form close on validation fail

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, colorbox

I am combining colorbox with JQuery validation plugin. However the div popup form close the form when validation failed or empty email which it shouldn't be. I have a simple - email, subscribe.

```
 <a id="hidden_link" style="display:none" href="#mc_embed_signup">empty</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://COM.us7.domain.com/subscribe/post?u=12345&amp;id=12345" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to Us</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
$("#hidden_link").colorbox({
    width: "30%",
    height: "200px",
    closeButton: false,
    scrolling: false,
    overlayClose: false,
    transition: "none",
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    href: "#mc_embed_signup",
    onComplete: function () {
        $('selector').validate({})
    }
});


$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate({
    rules: {
        'mce-EMAIL': {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Take it easy with the tag spam please.  The [tag:jquery-validation-engine] tag is for a totally different plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[jQuery validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) rules works with `name` selector

```
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate({
    rules: {
        EMAIL: { //changed 'mce-EMAIL' to EMAIL (name of the form filed)
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

---

jQuery Validate plugin automatically adds the `novalidate` attribute whenever it's not included.

<strike>Remove `novalidate` attribute from the `form`</strike>

---

Updated code after OP's comments

```
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate({
    rules: {
        EMAIL: { //changed 'mce-EMAIL' to EMAIL (name of the form filed)
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit().hide(); //this will submit and hide the form
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it is. The validation fired but it will close the form if validation fail.

Comment: @user1688346 why will it close the `form` ?

Comment: When I hit subscribe button, it will close the form. I do not know why.

Comment: <form action="http://COM.us7.domain.com/subscribe/post?u=12345&amp;id=12345" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to Us</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41380/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-user1688346)

Comment: @user1688346 why are you using `novalidate` in form ?

Comment: jQuery("#mc-embedded-subscribe").click(function () {
        parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
     });It is code from mailchimp.com. Anyhow looks like this is the issue.

Comment: @user1688346 yeah try after `removing` it

Comment: thanks. How do I conditionally close it only after validation success?

Comment: I don't see how the `novalidate` attribute should make any difference in this case.   If you inspect your DOM, you'll see that the jQuery Validate plugin automatically adds the 'novalidate` attribute whenever it's not included.